# Ext.net 2.0 ComboBox, tiny bug

Tags: ext.net, ext2

I have a very tricky issue which bothered me really long..

I was trying to use Ext.net 2.0 combobox to display options from remote DB. Everything works fine, but there is only one issue, when the page first loaded, if I do not change a selection of the combo, in c#, the combobox.value equals to the text instead of id.

Database is very easy: 'Test_table' has two columns, one called Tid, the other is TextContent.

My frontend code:

```
<ext:ComboBox ID="TestCombo" runat="server" Editable="false" DisplayField="TextContent"
   ValueField="Tid" TypeAhead="true" AllowBlank="false" EmptyText="Select a text
   id..." SelectOnFocus="true" FieldLabel="test text">
   <Store>
       <ext:Store ID="TestStore" runat="server" AutoLoad="true" AutoDataBind="true" 
             OnReadData="testStore_RefreshData">
           <Proxy>
               <ext:PageProxy>
               </ext:PageProxy>
           </Proxy>
           <Model>
                <ext:Model ID="Model1" runat="server" IDProperty="Tid">
                    <Fields>
                        <ext:ModelField Name="Tid" />
                        <ext:ModelField Name="TextContent" />
                    </Fields>
                </ext:Model>
           </Model>
        </ext:Store>
     </Store>
  </ext:ComboBox>
```

After click a save button, I try to add breakpoint to get var _M = TestCombo.value  However, it appears that if I click save after I changed the selection of the combobox, _M's value will be correct(equals to Tid value), otherwise, _M's value will be the TextContent..

Anyone has idea what caused this issue? Or does anyone have some good samples for Ext.net 2.0+ combobox code (read from remote db)?

Comment: why not go to the ext.net forums??

Comment: I think the same problem is discussed [here](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?22653).